# How to extract Below URL and Response Code from response data in Jmeter

Tags: java, regex, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

Below are the response datam, we are working to extract the response from the below URL's, but we are not able to extract using Regular Expression Extractor in Jmeter.

```
<td class="td-data2">http://elasticsearch.perf5.ua-north-1.bio.prod.platforms.build1:1340/</td>
<td class="td-data2">Failed to ping: Connection refused. - Connection failed: connect timed out</td>
```

Could any one help us on this issue which we are facing?

Comment: Above url is not working. Also try to ping this url from your machine where JMeter is running. It looks like its not reachable from JMeter machine

Comment: It need VPN connection and i am able to reach the above URL

Comment: @HemantPatel ABove is the response i am getting because cluster was down, I have to capture the response what ever it is coming through regular expression extractor. Could you idea about expression which i am able to capture

Comment: which part of the response you want to extract

Comment: We want to extract second line *Error message*

Answer (score 0):

Below is the regular expression

[image]
Now, you need to fetch the second error message if there are multiple matches.
Use ${ErrorMsg_2} or ${ErrorMsg_2_g1}
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Regular Expression Extractor**

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

**Debug Sampler**

[image: Debug Sampler]

**JMeter Tree**

[image]